# XML formatter plugin for maven

Tags: maven

What is the easiest way to format a single XML file using maven i.e. I'm looking for a maven plug-in that makes an XML file human readable. I've tried http://code.google.com/p/xml-formatter/ but for some reason I'm struggling to get it going and also I'm thinking that something like this would be part of a plug-in that is already on Maven Central or am I wrong? Is there maybe an ant task that I can delegate to?

**Edit:**

If now tried https://github.com/benalexau/xml-formatter which seems to be the latest version of the xml-formatter plug-in mentioned above. I got it working by deploying it to my local nexus repository using the following method:

- Downloaded the ZIP file from https://github.com/benalexau/xml-formatter
- Extracted the .jar and .pom files in zip://releases/org/technicalsoftwareconfiurationmanagement/maven-plugin/tscm-maven-plugin/*version-number*/
- Uploading the plug-in to my nexus repo using following maven command (on Linux):

  ```
  mvn deploy:deploy-file \
  -Durl="http://my/nexus/repo" \
  -DrepositoryId="3rd party" \
  -Dfile=tscm-maven-plugin-2.1.0.20111230154050.jar \
  -Dpackaging=maven-plugin \
  -DpomFile=tscm-maven-plugin-2.1.0.20111230154050.pom
  ```
- Adding the following to my project pom file:

  ```
  <plugin>
     <groupId>org.technicalsoftwareconfigurationmanagement.maven-plugin</groupId>
     <artifactId>tscm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.0.20111230154050</version>
     <configuration>
      <includes>
          <include>my-xml-file.xml</include>
      </includes>
      <excludes>
          <exclude>/target/</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
          <phase>test</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>xmlFormatter</goal>
          </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  ```
- Running

  ```
  mvn tscm:xmlFormatter
  ```

However... this seems to break my [soap-ui](http://www.soapui.org/) xml file by replacing "<" and ">" in the CDATA sections with &lt; and &gt; i.e. the plug-in doesn't really work for more complex use cases.

Comment: Please, what did you try and how did it not work for you?

Comment: Sander. Probably lack of knowledge on maven on my side. I've downloaded the plug-in jar, added the required entries in my pom file as described in http://code.google.com/p/xml-formatter/wiki/Documentation and installed the plugin in my nexus repository but when executing the formatter goal I get an error message basically saying that maven can't find the plugin associated with the command.

Comment: Since devils are in details, I still suggest you give details such as any POM changes you made to your project for this, or the command-line that has the plugin invocation, and then the real output from Maven.

Comment: My question is actually if there is an easier way i.e. thinking there should be something on maven central but sure I'll recreate the issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sander, I've gotten over the first hurdle. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can adapt my [cleanpom-maven-plugin](http://site.trajano.net/cleanpom-maven-plugin/) to do what you need, though it wasn't designed for that at the moment, but you can do in-place cleanups.  I just created a unit test that would show this.

You need to have an XSLT that would do your cleaning and put in inside META-INF of a JAR file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"
                xalan:indent-amount="4" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<!-- default copy -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="comment()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="comment()" />
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then add the following plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.trajano.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cleanpom-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>clean-web-xml</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <pomFile>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</pomFile>
                <xsltFileList>clean.xslt</xsltFileList>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>group</groupId>
          <artifactId>cleanxslt</artifactId>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Kinda kludgey, perhaps I will create one specific for this use case in the future as Eclipse does not allow setting the XML code style on save on the project level.

Answer (score 1):

Use **xml-format-maven-plugin**, which is available from Maven Central and [documented here](https://github.com/acegi/xml-format-maven-plugin). The current version properly handles complex XML files, including `CDATA`.

(disclaimer: I am the author of `xml-formatter` mentioned by the original questioner, as well as the `xml-format-maven-plugin` successor)

Answer (score 0):

Use the **xml-maven-plugin**, check it on http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/transformation.html

You can apply XSLT transformationS to the XML files using xsl:stylesheet and xsl:transform

```
<stylesheet>src/main/stylesheet.xsl</stylesheet>
```

Comment: This does not work too well because the output will be elsewhere rather than in-place.